# Why is TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED the default in Java?

Tags: java, transactions

The transaction tutorial explains in the section [Using Transactions to Preserve Data Integrity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#transactions_data_integrity):

> The default transaction isolation level depends on your DBMS. For example, for Java DB, it is TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED.

For my Postgresql database it is the same. But this does not seem to be the best, because only [`TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE) prevents all inconsistencies:

```
Isolation Level             │Transactions │Dirty Reads   │Non-Repeatable Reads│Phantom Reads
=============================================================================================
TRANSACTION_NONE            │Not supported│Not applicable│Not applicable      │Not applicable
TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED  │Supported    │Prevented     │Allowed             │Allowed
TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED│Supported    │Allowed       │Allowed             │Allowed
TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ │Supported    │Prevented     │Prevented           │Allowed
TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE    │Supported    │Prevented     │Prevented           │Prevented
```

Why is not the best option the default?

Comment: It's not the "default in Java". The default depends on the database, not the programming language. You should read up on databases a little bit first. If `SERIALIZABLE` really were "the best", why would there even be any other isolation levels?

Comment: Are you implying/supposing that "preventing all inconsistencies" should dictate the best default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an inverse relationship between transaction security and performance.
If you choose the best isolation level, you also get the worst performance.
You have to make a [trade-off](https://logicalread.com/optimize-mysql-perf-part-2-mc13/#.X03k-YuxVPY) between the two.

See this [benchmark](https://lchsk.com/benchmarking-concurrent-operations-in-postgresql.html) for more details.